# SQL: Get list of numbers not in use by other rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.1.17, and I have a table with account numbers. The acceptable range for an account number is a number between 1 and 1,000,000 (a six digit number). The column "acctnum" contains the account number. Selecting all the numbers in use is easy (SELECT acctnum FROM tbl_acct_numbers ORDER BY acctnum). What I would like to do is select all the numbers in the acceptable range that are not in use, that is, they aren't found in any rows within the column acctnum.

Comment: 1,000,000 (a six digit number) .. Is it supposed to be 1,00,000?

Comment: No, six digit number meaning a number between 000001 and 999999. Not including 1,000,000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    new_number
FROM
    generate_series(1, 1000000) AS new_number
        LEFT JOIN tbl_acct_numbers ON new_number = acctnum
WHERE
    acctnum IS NULL;
```

Comment: This query took 519 seconds, but actually worked unlike some of the others on this page.

Comment: Do you have an index on acctnum? And do you realy need ALL numbers or just 10 or 100? If so, use a LIMIT.

Comment: I actually only need 9 numbers, but in a certain way. I have ranges of numbers, and I need the next available number for each range. The ranges are 100,000 - 200,000, 200,000 - 300,000, etc. So I could execute this query with LIMIT 1 for each range 9 times, which is what I did. I put this query in a function passing in the lower/upper bounds, and called it 9 times, and there I have it. Thanks!

Comment: Frank, thanks for this post - I've been trying to figure out a solution and your post worked perfectly well. I couldn't be happier with the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the series of numbers from 1-1,000,000 and then MINUS the results of your query.

```
select * from generate_series(1,1000000)
EXCEPT
SELECT acctnum FROM tbl_acct_numbers;
```

Comment: Confirmed, MINUS is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. MINUS is the Oracle version. The quivalent in postGreSQl is "EXCEPT"  http://www.faqs.org/docs/ppbook/x5802.htm#USINGEXCEPT

Comment: Aah, OK well then it works. Also an acceptable solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do this?  I assume the reason you want to find unused numbers is so that you can use them.

But consider that the numbers might not be there because someone *did* use them in the past, and deleted the row from the database.  So if you find that account number and re-use it for a new account, you could be assigning a number that was previously used and was deleted for a reason.

If there are any historical documents in other systems that reference that account number, they might mistakenly be associated with the new account using the same number.

However, as long as you have considered this, you can find unused id's in the following way:

```
SELECT t1.acctnum-1 AS unused_acctnum
FROM MyTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable t2 ON t2.acctnum = t1.acctnum-1
WHERE t2.acctnum IS NULL;
```

Granted, this doesn't find *all* the unused acctnums, only a set of them that are 1 less than a number that's in use.  But that might give you enough to work with.

---

The answer from @Alex Howansky does give you all unused acctnums, but it may return a large set of rows.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but on the application side, I am taking care not to use numbers that have been used before, so you are only seeing half of the picture. This query did not work for me however because my col type for acctnum is not integer but character varying. The error message says to use explicit type casts, but I don't know where to put them in the query (never done type casting in sql).

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
  from generate_series(1, 1000000) as acctnum
  where acctnum not in (select acctnum from tbl_acct_numbers);
```

Comment: Alex, Your query would give all the account numbers in tbl_account_numbers which are not in the 1-1000000 range.

Comment: Whoops @Rajesh, you're right -- I got the two sides of the query reversed, thanks for pointing that out. (Edited.)